# To Add all prime digits present in a number in java. what's error in this code?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]){  

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ; 

     System.out.print("Enter String: "); 
     String str = sc.nextLine();  
     int n=str.length();
     int count=0;
     char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(isPrime(strArray[i]))

        {
            count=count+strArray[i];
        }
    }
   System.out.println (count);   

} 



private static boolean isPrime(int num)
{   
  if(num==1 ||(num!=2 && num%2==0))
  {
      return false;
  }
 else
 {
     for(int i=2;i<num/2;i++)
  {
      if(num%i==0)
      return false;
  }

 }
return true;
}
```

I'm converting string to character array to check for prime and calling the function 
It's not giving the correct output.
Input:
123
Output:
5
I'm not getting the error here. what's the error in this code?

Comment: what output do you expect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `strArray[i]` to `isPrime`, if you are passing '3', you are not checking if the number 3 is prime, you are checking if the numeric value of the character '3' is prime.

Assuming your input contains only digits, try to change the code to :

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(isPrime(strArray[i]-'0'))

    {
        count=count+strArray[i]-'0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Q: the char value, is the numeric ASCII value, right?

Comment: @Eran- It's still giving the correct output. for input 123 the output is 101 instead of 5.

Comment: @Prabh did you change the code in both places?

Comment: @Prabh You probably forgot to change this line - `count=count+strArray[i]-'0'` - so instead of getting 2+3, you are getting 50+51

Comment: @JordiCastilla It's the unicode value, which in the case of digits as well as other basic characters is the same as the ASCII value.

Comment: @Eran- Yeah..Got it now!! but for 123456 o/p is 14.

Comment: @Prabh I'm getting 10 for 123456, as should be.

Comment: @Eran - it should be 10 only... but I'm getting 14. what's wrong now??

Comment: @Prabh I have no idea. It's working fine for me. Are you sure you are passing `123456` to your program?